# How can I distinguish 0 and empty string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say

```
a="";  // empty String
b=0;
```

then

```
a==b;  // returns true
```

What Test could I build to return true only if I compare two empty strings or two zero's?

Comment: here is a really good post of == vs. === http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the strict comparison operator, `===`. This will not use JavaScript's default type coercion, so you will get the correct result.

```
"" === 0; // false
```

Answer (score 1):

use === instead of == for checking undifined and zero or false compare